# Dojo tlmSiblingOfDojo not working, paths are not relative

Tags: javascript, dojo, path, require

Hi all and thanks for the help!

I cannot get Dojo require to look for relative paths to the baseUrl. The request path requires for my tManager/pageList.js object are aways "/tManager/pageList.js" when they should be "js/tManager/pageList.js". It works just fine when I add "js/" to the require path but i'd really like these all to be relative. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dojoConfig = {
    baseUrl: "js/",
    isDebug: true,
    tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,
    async: false,
    packages: [
        { name: "dojo", location: "lib/dojo" },
        { name: "dijit", location: "lib/dijit" },
        { name: "dojox", location: "lib/dojox" },
        { name: "tManager", location: "tManager/" }
    ]
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/ready",
    "tManager/pageList.js"
], function (dom, ready, pageList) {
    ready(function () {
        alert("hello world");
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is my folder structure:
\
\js\
\js\lib\
\js\lib\dojo\
\js\lib\dijit\
\js\lib\dojox\
\js\tManager\

Once again thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `tManager/pageList.js` is an AMD module get rid of `.js` extension in `require`. Otherwise your are performing [generic script injection](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd#generic-script-injection) instead of loading a module.

```
require([
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojo/ready",
    "tManager/pageList"  // <= do not use .js extension for AMD modules
], function (dom, ready, pageList) {
    ready(function () {
        alert("hello world");
    });
});
```